# Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have a problem with my custom module.. in the form i get that error : Fatal error: Call to a member function `setData()` on **boolean** in `/wwwroot/whitelabel/01/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php` on **line 141**

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Integravet_Associar>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Integravet_Associar>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <associar before="Mage_Adminhtml">Integravet_Associar_Adminhtml</associar>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <associar>
                    <file>integravet_associar.xml</file>
                </associar>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <integravet_associar>
                <class>Integravet_Associar_Helper</class>
            </integravet_associar>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <integravet_associar>
                <class>Integravet_Associar_Block</class>
            </integravet_associar>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <integravet_associar>
                <class>Integravet_Associar_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>integravet_associar_resource</resourceModel>
            </integravet_associar>
            <integravet_associar_resource>
                <class>Integravet_Associar_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <associar>
                        <table>integravet_associar</table>
                    </associar>
                </entities>
            </integravet_associar_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <integravet_associar_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </integravet_associar_write>
            <integravet_associar_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </integravet_associar_read>
            <integravet_associar_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Integravet_Associar</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </integravet_associar_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

My adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
<menu>
    <integravet translate="title" module="integravet_ramo">
        <title>Integravet</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <associar translate="title" module="integravet_associar">
                <title>Associar Ramo de Atividade</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/associar/index</action>
            </associar>
        </children>
    </integravet>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <integravet translate="title">
                    <title>Integravet</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <associar translate="title" module="integravet_associar">
                            <title>Associar Ramo de Atividade</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </associar>
                    </children>
                </integravet>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

My controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: williansugiyama
 * Date: 22/08/17
 * Time: 15:49
 */
class Integravet_Associar_Adminhtml_AssociarController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

protected function _initAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('integravet_associar/set_time')->_addBreadcrumb('Ramos de atividade', 'Ramos de atividade');
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction(){
    $this->_initAction();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction(){
    $ramoId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar')->load($ramoId);
    if($ramoModel->getId() || $ramoId == 0) {
        Mage::register('associar_data', $ramoModel);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('integravet_associar/set_time');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb('Ramos de atividade', 'Ramos de atividade');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb('Descrição do ramo', 'Descrição do ramo');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')
            ->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('integravet_associar/adminhtml_associar_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('integravet_associar/adminhtml_associar_edit_tabs')
            );
        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('Ramo não existe.');
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction() {
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function saveAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0) {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0) {
                    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
                } else {
                    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar');
                }

                $ramoModel->setCreatedTime( Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate() );
                $ramoModel->addData($postData)
                    ->setId()
                    ->setcreated_at(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
                    ->save();
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            }  catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setramoData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
            $ramoModel->addData($postData)->setupdated_at(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getparam('id'))
                ->save();
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }


}

public function deleteAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0) {
        try {
            $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar');
            $ramoModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')->delte());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Ramo Deletado com sucesso');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
}
```

My Grid.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: williansugiyama
 * Date: 22/08/17
 * Time: 14:29
 */

class Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_associar';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'integravet_associar';

        $this->_headerText = 'Associar ramos de atividade';
        $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Associar';

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

My Edit.php

```
class Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'adminhtml_associar';
        $this->_controller = 'integravet_associar';
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', 'Salvar associação');
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', 'Deletar associação');
    }


    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('associar_data') && Mage::registry('associar_data')->getId()) {
            return 'Editar Associação ' . $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('associar_data')->getTitle());
        } else {
            return 'Adicionar Associação';
        }
    }

}
```

My tabs.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: williansugiyama
 * Date: 22/08/17
 * Time: 14:51
 */

class Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('associar_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle('Informações do ramo');
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label' => 'About the movie',
            'title' => 'About the movie',
            'content' => $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('integravet_associar/adminhtml_associar_edit_tab_form')
                ->toHtml()
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

My Form.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: williansugiyama
 * Date: 22/08/17
 * Time: 14:56
 */

class Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ),
                'method' => 'post',
            )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

My Tab/Form.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: williansugiyama
 * Date: 22/08/17
 * Time: 14:58
 */

class   Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form', array (
            'legend' => 'Informações do ramo'
        ));

        $fieldset
            ->addField('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Ramo de Atividade',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'name',
            ))
            ->addField('id_erp', 'text', array (
                'label' => 'ID ERP',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'id_erp' => 'id_erp'
            ))
            ->addField('website_id','multiselect', array (
                'label' => 'teste',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_website_collection')->toOptionArray(),
            ));


        if(Mage::registry('associar_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('associar_data')->getData());
        }

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Comment: `->setcreated_at(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())` - this line in save action seems wrong. It should be `setCreatedAt`

Comment: Same problem ;/

Comment: 8 8.5412 45715192 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout( ??? ) .../AssociarController.php:36 i found this line on error log

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `blockGroup`, controller are wrong in **Edit.php**, please update it to:

`Edit.php`

```
class Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'integravet_associar';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_associar';
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', 'Salvar associação');
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', 'Deletar associação');
}


public function getHeaderText()
{
    if (Mage::registry('associar_data') && Mage::registry('associar_data')->getId()) {
        return 'Editar Associação ' . $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('associar_data')->getTitle());
    } else {
        return 'Adicionar Associação';
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but my form page are blank now.. My class form named : 'Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit_Tab_Form'

Comment: Have you the same error ?

Comment: Not the same error, but don't render the form.

Comment: 'Integravet_Associar_Block_Adminhtml_Associar_Edit_Tab_Form' ? i told the `Edit.php` not `Form.php`

Comment: Yeah, I change in Edit.php, but now i have a blank page rather than my form.

Comment: You had it before my update ?

Comment: No, i had it after your update.

Comment: I get this error now : $form.submit is not a function on submit my form admin..